# Custom CIFilter subclass returns image with scale out of whack

Tags: ios, core-image, cifilter

I'm new to writing CIFilters, and I'm stuck on this problem. Here is my source image being displayed in a UIImageView with contentMode set to Aspect Fit:

[image: source image]

Here is the image returned from my CIFilter object being displayed in the same UIImageView:

[image: filtered image]

I've tried copying over the original scale and orientation from my source image to the UIImage being constructed from the CIImage returned from the filter with no luck.

What might be causing this?

I'm thinking I'm doing something wrong in my CIFilter class. I am starting to suspect something in my outputImage method:?

```
func outputImage() -> CIImage? {
    if let inputImage = inputImage {
        let dod = inputImage.extent()
        if let kernel = kernel {
            let args = [inputImage as AnyObject]
            let dod = inputImage.extent().rectByInsetting(dx: -1, dy: -1)
            return kernel.applyWithExtent(dod, roiCallback: {
                (index, rect) in
                return rect.rectByInsetting(dx: -1, dy: -1)
                }, arguments: args)
        }
    }
    return nil
}
```

Comment: Ok, so I re-tried using a built in "CISepiaTone" filter, and encountered the same problem.  it has nothing to do with the implementation of my custom filter. Still can't figure out what the actual problem is though

Comment: I'm not certain but my bet is this has mote to do with the UIView than the CIImage.